# Eclipse Groovy and autocompletion

Tags: eclipse, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using the current version of SpringSource Tool Suite with the Groovy/Grails plugin installed. I can understand that when defining and using "pure" groovy classes/objects there are cases that make code autocompletion difficult.

But if I use Java classes in the groovy class shouldn't the autocompletion feature work as intended? For example i'm trying to use "readFileToString" from the org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils class. Eclipse only suggests groovy methods for this class, there is no static method in the list from FileUtils class.

Is it a problem with my installation of STS or maybe the groovy editor in STS just doesn't support autocompletion for pure java classes?

Comment: Please paste the code snippet exactly as it is when you want to do content assist.  The Groovy Editor is based off of an antlr parser, which does fail to parse certain files with syntax errors.  It could be that the file you are trying to perform content assist on has syntax errors that is preventing content assist from working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also want to make sure you are on the latest and greatest version of the Groovy-Eclipse plug-in.  It has grown by leaps and bounds over the past 6 months, and each release just gets better.  I had a similar issue with finding methods from a parent class, and it was resolved after an upgrade.  I pick up Groovy Eclipse via the download within SpringSource Tool Suite.