# Eclipse content assist not working for Java objects within Groovy files

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, content-assist

I found this question [Eclipse Groovy and autocompletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312596/eclipse-groovy-and-autocompletion) and am experiencing the same issue, however, it is almost three years hence and I am using the current version of the *Groovy Eclipse* plugin, and there do not appear to be any syntax errors that would be confusing *ANTLR*.

I also tried using the *Groovy/Grails Tool Suite*, and got the same results.

I have mocked up a simple test case under which the content assist works for *Groovy* objects' methods, and for *Java* objects' static members, but not *Java* objects' methods.

**The Groovy class:**

```
package test_groovy

import test_groovy.FooJava

class FooGroovy
{
    def fooJava = [2, "baz"] as FooJava

    def x = 4

    def FooGroovy()
    {
        // empty constructor    
    }

    def useFooJava()
    {
        // only displays Groovy methods, not the java ones
        def str = fooJava.getStr()
        println "str: ${str}"

        // static members like this *can* be found via content assist
        def str2 = FooJava.FOO_STR
        println "str2: ${str2}"

        // This is also not found via content assist
        def str3 = fooJava.dumpToStr()
        println "str3: ${str3}"
    }

    def fooBar()
    {
        return x + 3
    }

    static void main(def args)
    {
        def fooGroovy = [] as FooGroovy

        // Groovy object methods can be found via content assist
        def res = fooGroovy.fooBar()
        println "res: ${res}"

        fooGroovy.useFooJava()
    }
}
```

**The Java class:**

```
package test_groovy;

public class FooJava
{
    private long bar;
    private String str;

    public static final String FOO_STR = "foo";

    public FooJava(long bar, String str)
    {
        super();
        this.bar = bar;
        this.str = str;
    }

    public long getBar()
    {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(long bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public String getStr()
    {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str)
    {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public String dumpToStr()
    {
        return new String("Str: " + str + ", bar: " + bar);
    }

}
```

I am using *Eclipse* Kepler Service Release 2, *Groovy* compiler 2.0.7 and *Groovy Eclipse* plugin version 2.8.0.xx-20130703-1600-e43-RELEASE.

Under the **Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced** preferences menu, I have made sure all the *Java* options are checked off in addition to **Groovy Content** (Java Non-Type, Java, Java type Proposals).

Since this does seem to work in general for some, I am wondering what I could be missing here that would allow content assist to work for *Java* object methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was continuing to think about this, and had a thought which I just tested out which allows content-assist to work, albeit under less-*Groovy* conditions:

It appears that the root of the problem is that *Groovy Eclipse* can't do auto-complete on *Java* objects if they are declared in a *Groovy* way using `def`, i.e.:

```
def fooJava = [2, "baz"] as FooJava
def fooJava2 = new FooJava(3, "bar")
```

even though in both of these cases, the type is known at compile time. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that `def` is essentially an alias for `Object`, and even though the type is technically known, it is probably treated as `Object`, and so that's the type on which the content-assist operates.

If I declare it in the traditional *Java* way, i.e.:

```
FooJava fooJava3 = new FooJava(4, "foo")
```

Content assist then allows me to find the members, methods, etc. of the `FooJava` object.

So, I can certainly do this in the future to work around the issue, but I do wonder if there is any way to essentially have my cake and eat it too.

i.e. Has anyone found a way to get content assist to work on *Java* objects declared via the `def` syntax, so long as the type is known?

Comment: I suspect it is that Groovy-Eclipse just doesn't handle that inferencing case. I'd raise a jira against groovy-eclipse: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE

Comment: The ticket was originally closed by the *Groovy Eclipse* team, but I have just reopened the ticket asking them to reconsider.

Comment: With the recent news that *Codehaus* is [shutting down](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2892227/open-source-tools/codehaus-the-once-great-house-of-code-has-fallen.html), I'm not sure where the *Jira* for *Groovy Eclipse* will end up. It appears the new wiki home is at [Github](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki), but that still refers to the *Codehaus Jira* as I write this.

Comment: *Codehaus* has shutdown all its services, and there's no indication that development on *Groovy Eclipse* is continuing, although there is an open request for that from a primary *Groovy* language developer: https://twitter.com/CedricChampeau/status/593347714244575232

Comment: Yes, I would say the home for groovy-eclipse is now github. Users are already raising issues there, but there is no-one actively developing it. I did a one off upgrade yesterday to get it vaguely working on Eclipse 4.5 (update site for that is on the project wiki at github).

Comment: @AndyClement: Thanks for the update and the upgrade!

Comment: a bit late here, I was using groovy for couple of years now. But with old ggts. Also dont find the groovy-eclipse plugin work well with eclipse (tested luna and above). Is groovy plugin for eclipse under developement? Or is the old beautiful language dying due to lack of support capital?

Comment: @Mahesha999: It's had a small number of commits in 2016, but I would say it's definitely not under active development (see https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/graphs/contributors and note the activity trail-off. I use Groovy Eclipse currently with Eclipse Mars.

Comment: Is groovy eclipse working well with Mars? Am on Luna with Groovy Eclipse plugin. Auto completion works at only first Ctrl+Spacebar after eclipse  restart. After that it gives a beep sound saying "No completion available." in eclipse' status bar.

Comment: It works for me on Mars with the caveats I mentioned in my answer above (e.g. it won't work with Groovy-style variables).

Comment: FYI, the project appears to currently be active again, based on what I currently see at https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/graphs/contributors. I last checked on that link in July 2016, and it appears that from about 2017 on, there has been significant activity on this project.