# Java Code Completion in Groovy Files in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, eclipse-mars, groovy-eclipse

I don't get any Java code completion in a groovy editor in Eclipse Mars. It seems that in older Eclipse versions the Java completion was available: [Eclipse content assist not working for Java objects within Groovy files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354680/eclipse-content-assist-not-working-for-java-objects-within-groovy-files)
I have a newly installed Mars and use Groovy-Eclipse from here: http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.5/
Does anybody have a solution for that problem? Is there any other Groovy editor that does the autocompletion for Java right?

Comment: Venturing into opinion, but try the community version of intellij

Comment: In intellij the auto completion works like a charm! Thanks for this suggestion!